# Good resource for graph theory

Tags: graphs, reference-request

Frankly speaking I have many problem with symbols in graph such as (s:s') or v\S or some symbols such as those that I mentioned . Can anyone suggest a good resource or a good tutorial on the net that has been discussed about these symbols and have clarified these symbols ?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27480/what-are-good-books-to-learn-graph-theory

Comment: Note that notation varies significantly from author to author.

Comment: thank you so much